# c array on a single line

Tags: c, arrays

I have to do a bubble sort with pointers for my class.
I am having trouble with the output
I want every array sort to be on a single line, not individual lines for each element.

Here is an array example that I would want to print.
*I flipped the 1 and 9 to ensure that I was printing the proper value, not the location, when it was returning just one number.*

[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]

Here is what it prints

[9]

[2]

[3]

[4]

[5]

[6]

[7]

[8]

[1]

How do I get this sample array onto just one line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

int val[] = {9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1};
int i;

int main(){
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++
        { printf ("[%d]\n", val[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}   //end main
```

Now I have read that you cant output to one line.  I keep reading that you need each element to output individually.  The prof has the sample output for the bubble pointer showing that all elements of the array remain on the same line.  What am I missing?

*FYI this is not the bubble sort with pointer.  I am just needing help getting this sample array to output properly.*
**This must be in C, NOT C++, or C#.**

Comment: Replace the new-line (`\n`)  by a space/blank?

Comment: `putchar('['); for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX-1; i++) printf("%d, ", i); printf("%d]\n", i);`?

Comment: @alk thats getting there it now outputs [9] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [1].

Comment: you should know that your code does not include a `bubble` sort, nor any other kind of sort.   You might want to google for the bubble sort algorithm example in C.  For instance: <http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort>

Comment: this statement: *I flipped the 1 and 9 to ensure that I was printing the proper value, not the location,* strongly indicates that you do not yet know how data is stored in memory.  Suggest you discuss this with your instructor.

Comment: when I include the bubble sort it will print the array as I wish?

Comment: Yes I do not fully understand.  My terminology is most likely wrong.  I am a total noob.  I understand that location returns a multi digit number, 6849753 for example, which is the address.  I switched the 1 and 9 to ensure I wasnt returning something else in the code that I did not see.  An 9 digit array is counted by the system by starting at 0 and going to 8.  I should have said I switched the 1 and 9 to ensure I wasnt returning a COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see why you don't just remove the `\n`, which causes the newline.  Then separate out the different parts of your output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 9

int val[] = {9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1};
int i;

int main(void){
    putchar('[');
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      if (i == MAX - 1)
        printf ("%d", val[i]);
      else
        printf ("%d, ", val[i]);
    }

    puts("]");
    return (0);
}   //end main
```

You cannot print the `[` in the loop, or else it will print every time.  Then, in the loop you want to print a comma unless you are at your last element where no elements should be printed next (`if (i == MAX - 1`).  Finally you print the newline and the closing bracket at the end once the loop finishes.  Make note that [`puts()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) automatically prints a newline.

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for.  Now I can move on to finishing my assignment. iRove you rock!

Comment: @CHEIF I'm glad this helped you.

Comment: @Oka Yes, that would probably be more understandable.  Should I edit with your change or leave it since it is already in the comments?

Comment: @iRove Totally up to you.

Comment: @Oka Hmm.  I'll leave it then - people can easily see it was your contribution this way.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Oka I am using puTTY to link to the schools server, then compiling with gcc.  When I use iRove's code it works just fine, when I use Oka's code it faults out with the for loop saying its only allowed in c99 mode then notes to use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to complete.  I dont think I can change the option, or I could, but they dont want us to.

Comment: @CHIEF Then simply move the declaration of `i` outside of the initializer section of the loop. `int i; for (i = 0 ...`